# Is C# string.LastIndexOf always culture specific?

Tags: c#, string, indexof, lastindexof

x is a string in any language/culture and want to find the last dot in the string:

```
int y = x.LastIndexOf(".");
```

Is the result (y) culture independent or not?
Why?

Comment: What culture-specific treatment are you expecting to encounter here?

Comment: That was my thought.  Isn't a period more or less a period everywhere?

Comment: There's no numeric or temporal parsing/formatting going on so interpretation in a culture-specific manner doesn't apply to this.

Comment: Is c# find the last dot in all languages? Are there any culture which is not to recognize the dots?

Comment: CultureInfo is only relevant to culture-specific serialization like with dates and currency. A `.` is a `.` in a generic string anywhere on earth. Its only when a specific context is applied, for example `.` has a special meaning for numbers in certain cultures as a decimal separator, where other cultures don't use `.` for that and use `,` instead. But a string in and of itself is just a string. In this example its not applying any sort of meaning to `.`, just checking if it is there. So the string and the character are compared verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

`LastIndexOf` is culture insensitive. The value is matched if the unicode values of the characters are the same.

You can find more information on this in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8) section of Microsoft Docs.

In order to perform a culture-specific char search you'll have to make use of [CompareInfo.LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8)